# How to resize glyphicon icon horizontally?

Tags: css, icons, glyphicons

[image]

I want to resize 'glyphicon-menu-right' icon horizontally, but not vertically. I know the icon can be resized using the 'font-size' property, in that case: the icon gets resized with both height and width (both horizontally and vertically). But I only want to change the width (horizontal size)

Answer (score 0):

You can resize glyphicon icon horizontally using **transform:scale(2,1)** CSS property. where scale's first parameter is for horizontal size & second parameter is for vertical size.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right" aria-hidden="true" style="transform: scale(2,1);"></span>
```